# Electromagnet Options to Vibrate Long String at 80Hz

Tags: electromagnetic, physics

I recently completed a popular maker DIY where I recreated a product called SlowDance. You have see the original in action here https://player.vimeo.com/video/262079608

This product functions on the premise that an Electromagnet vibrates the object in the frame at around 80hz and then strobes LEDs lights slightly slower than 80hz producing the illusion of slow motion (the LED strobing is not discernible to your naked eye). For my DIY version I used the electromagnet, Arduino sketch, and PCB available in this kit: 
https://www.tindie.com/products/Nick64/jf-slomo-slow-motion-frame-diy-kit/

Now I'm interested in creating a scaled-up version of this frame but lack the know-how from a electrical engineering standpoint.

The intent for the scaled-up version would be to vibrate a 4-6ft long string of unknown composition at 80hz. I would then anchor the string taught at one side of the frame and attached it to the electromagnet at the other.

My question is fairly simple, what type of electromagnet would be best suited to accomplish vibrating a 4-6ft long string at 80Hz and getting an appreciable range of motion out of the string (and any object I subsequently attached to it)?

Comment: Take the [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: use an electric motor coupled to a crank and a pushrod, like a piston in an internal combustion engine ..... you can build something from Lego just a proof of concept ... scale down the speed (probably won't hold together at 4800 RPM)

Comment: @jsotola do you mean something like... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wfo2QqkXMU... (first engine shown in the video). I thought about this but wasn't confident I could get something to vibrate at 80Hz using that approach?

Comment: no, in reverse ..... you turn the wheel using a motor .... the piston reciprocates .... string is tied to the piston .... the string end moves with the piston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a string, it will be resonant.

You can probably use a pair of supermagnets either side of the string (old hard drive) , and put your AC current through the string.  You want a heavy guitar/bass string. In fact get a guitar and start playing with that on the bass string.

The string is the electromagnet. The magnets field must be across the string (i.e. these magnets are attracting each other), and this makes the string move from side to side, parallel to the gap as you pass current though it.

The magnets will be down fairly close to the nut or bridge. Here are two small 3/8" fridge super magnets, held 3.2mm apart with some hotmelt. The signal generator is connected to each end of the string, and is putting 130mA through the string.

[image].[image]

It is very hard to tune the signal generator onto the fundamental, the resonance is so narrow - about 0.2Hz at 100Hz

You cannot make a string move, except in a resonant fashion. Away from its resonant frequency it just sits there - that's what resonance is all about.

This also means that you have to make the string set the frequency, not the electronics.

You can also do it mechanically see Wheel Harp or Hurdy Gurdy. You could also make a little plucker than plucks it every few seconds - which would give the satisfying view of the vibration decaying.

BTW, the challenge of this is making a strobe frequency that is 0.3Hz off from the strings frequency.

Another approach is the skipping rope one.

Yet another is to use flourescent nylon for your string (Weed whipper line), and UV/Blue leds for the strobe. (attach a tiny super magnet to the line, or use hard-drive coil, or loudspeaker cone etc etc)

Comment: Interesting Idea... for the simplicity of design / construction I'd like to keep the electromagnet(s) in only one side of the scaled-up frame so really looking for a solution on how to physically move a string with an electromagnet and have that energy transfer into motion through the entire 4-6ft length...

Comment: As Henry says, isn't this a guitar in reverse? Then excite the string with something like a guitar pickup!

Comment: I have been thinking more about what henry said and that let me down the hole of... low frequency signal generation over a conductive string... Demonstrated best here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSsYM78JGwo ... Is this basically what you mean henry?

Comment: Neat Henry, I get it now. I'll go pick up a cheap DIY signal generator and then start experimenting with different string materials (notes). Re the challenge of strobe frequency.... that is all controlled via an Arduino program/sketch, shouldn't be that hard to change the strobe frequency once the resonance is dialed in... assuming the resonance frequency of the string does not change with age/use.

Comment: resonance does change with temperature, humidity etc. Why do musician tune ll the time? You are better to make a string oscillator, and get the circuit to measure that and work from it. Pull a hard drive apart. It has a fantastic pair of magnets for this job, and a motor coil you could probably attach to a string. hard drives use exactly this arrangement to move the heads . They are very fast - quite possibly you could keep it intact and use the head arm to push the string sideways.

Comment: Not to mention that the "dancing object" itself will affect the resonance frequency quite a bit.

Comment: @HenryCrun - Maybe not. Hard drive mechanisms are not intended to be operated under transverse loads, so a string under tension may well cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go old school on it and use an electrically driven tuning fork.

[This gadget vibrates at approximately 80Hz.](https://www.eiscolabs.com/products/ph0746cnc?variant=6551305284)

It is intended for this kind of thing.  It even includes a screw to attach the string.

[image]